# Login in AngularJs using Controller Services, Web api and MVC model class

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a Login form control in AngularJs. But the Username and Password should be fetched from the model class (Doctor.cs). Using the services controller and Web Api, if he is an authenticated doctor then he should be redirected to *DoctorPanel.cshtml*

login.cshtml

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPwd" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()" data-ng-disabled="!formLogin.$valid">login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Model class Doctor.cs

```
public class Doctor
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

DoctorsAPIController.cs

```
public class DoctorsAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private DigitalHealthWebContext db = new DigitalHealthWebContext();

        // GET: api/DoctorsAPI
        public List<Doctor> GetDoctors()
        {
            return db.Doctors.ToList();
        }

        //public static List<Doctor> GetDoctors()
        //{
        //    var query = from doctor in DigitalHealthWebContext.Doctors
        //                select doctor;
        //    return db.Doctors.ToList();
        //}

        // GET: api/DoctorsAPI/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Doctor))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDoctor(int id)
        {
            Doctor doctor = await db.Doctors.FindAsync(id);
            if (doctor == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(doctor);
        }

        // PUT: api/DoctorsAPI/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutDoctor(int id, Doctor doctor)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != doctor.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(doctor).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DoctorExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/DoctorsAPI
        [ResponseType(typeof(Doctor))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostDoctor(Doctor doctor)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = doctor.Id }, doctor);
        }

        // DELETE: api/DoctorsAPI/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Doctor))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteDoctor(int id)
        {
            Doctor doctor = await db.Doctors.FindAsync(id);
            if (doctor == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Doctors.Remove(doctor);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(doctor);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool DoctorExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Doctors.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
```

I have 3 javascript files namely module.js, service.js, controller.js.

module.js
    var app = angular.module("docModule", ["ngRoute"]);

```
    //services.js 
    app.service('docService', function ($http) {

        this.getDoctors = function () {
            return $http.get("/api/DoctorsAPI");
        }
});
```

Finally the controller comes

controller.js

```
app.controller('docController', function ($scope, docService) {

    loadRecords();

    function loadRecords() {

        var promiseGet = docService.getDoctors(); //The MEthod Call from service

        promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.doctors = pl.data },
              function (errorPl) {
                  $log.error('failure loading Doctor', errorPl);
              });
    }
});
```

Comment: basically you need to create a spa, & redirect on other route when use is authorized

Comment: I am new to AngularJs. Can I get the code for how we can write the functio n or service through web api and fetch in AngularJs html page.

Comment: do look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/single-page-application-spa-using-angularjs-web-api-and-m/